# could tell what i did wrong in the assembly(riscv32), it is printing the warnings wrongly. I'm using the rars simulator

Tags: assembly, riscv, riscv32, rars-simulator

I'm having problems with my code, it just prints "Invalid direction", and the matrix information is correct, my entry was this one .word 3 1 1 1 0 5 2 2 0 1 6 4.

Below is an explanation of how the program should work.

Enemy ships are placed in a string called "ships" present in the area
data (.data), which must be read by the insert_ships function at the beginning of the game. THE
string ships has the following pattern. The number of ships is informed in the first line
inserted. Each of the following lines has a ship. The lines that specify ships
have 4 values, separated by a space, as follows: the first value is the ship's layout
0 for a horizontal ship and 1 for a vertical ship; the second value is the length of the
ship; the third value is the ship's starting line and; the fourth value is the ship's starting column.
Observe the Example:
3
1 5 1 1
0 5 2 2
0 1 6 4

The positioning of ships is above the result in the following positioning:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnKd4.png)

The function inserts vessels must verify the validity of the positioning of the ships,
generating an error message for the following situations:
-The ship's position is invalid. Example: 0 3 11 7
-The ship extrapolates according to the dimensions of the matrix. Example: 0 4 2 7
-The overlap occurs on ships. Example 0 4 2 2 and 1 3 0 3

Now the full code, what's wrong with it?

```
.data
campo:          .space 400  
.align 2
navios:                 .word 3 1 1 1 0 5 2 2 0 1 6 4 
letras:                 .asciz "abcdefgh"
arrume_sobreposicao :   .asciz "Arrange the Overlay\n"
erro_nav:               .asciz "ship out of bounds\n"
erro_direcao:           .asciz "Invalid direction\n"
.text

main:
       la t4, letras
       la t5, navios
       lw t6, 0(t5)   # n = *np
       addi t5,t5,1

       li t1,0
       li t2,100
       la t3, campo
       li a0, '~'
for1:
      beq t1,t2, endfor1
      #sw a0,0(t3)
      lbu a0,0(t3)
      addi t3,t3,4
      addi t1,t1,1
      j for1

endfor1:
      li t1,0

for2:
    beq t1,t6, endfor2
        lbu a0, 0(t5)   # dir
        addi t5,t5,4
        lbu a1, 0(t5)   # size
        addi t5,t5,4
        lbu a2, 0(t5)   # x
        addi t5,t5,4
        lbu a3, 0(t5)   # y
        addi t5,t5,4
        jal ra, insert_ships
        addi t1,t1,1
        j for2

endfor2:
    li a7, 10   # sai sem codigo de retorno
    ecall    # fim do programa

insert_ships:
    li t1,1
    li t2, 10
        bne a1, t1, endif0 # if dir == 1     
        
        bgt a2,t2, fracasso1
        bgt a3, t2,fracasso1
        add t1, a3, a1   # x + size
      
        bge t1, t2, else1   # if not (y + size >= 10)
        blt a3, zero, else1  # if not (y < 0)
        blt a2, zero, else1  # if not (x < 0)
        bge a2, t2, else1   # if not (x >= 10)
        # letra em t3, i em t1, x em a2 e y em a3
        li t1, 0
        
fracasso1:
    la a0, arrume_sobreposicao 
        li a7, 4
        ecall
        
        #j 
        
        
for3:
    bge t1,a2, endfor3   #   i < size
        la t5, campo
        add t5, t5, a2   #  m + x
        add t2, a3, t1   # y + i
        slli t4, t2, 3     # 8 * (y + i)
        slli t2, t2, 1     # 2 * (y + i)
        add t5, t5, t4   # m + x + 8*(y + i)
        add t5, t5, t2   # m + x + 10*(y + i)
        lbu t2, 0(t5)
        li t4, '~'
        bne t2, t3, else7    #  if (m[x][y + i] == '~') ...
        sb t3, 0(t5)     # m[x][y+i] = letra
        j endif7
else7:
        la a0, arrume_sobreposicao 
        li a7, 4
        ecall
            #j endfor1    # break
        #j endfor3
endif7:
        addi t1, t1, 1
        j for3
endfor3:
            #j endif1
        j endfor3
else1:
        la a0, erro_nav 
        li a7, 4
        ecall
endif1:
endif0:
    li t2, 10
        bne a1, zero, endif2   # if dir == 0    caso horizontal
        bgt a2,t2, fracasso1
        bgt a3, t2,fracasso1
        bge a2,t2, fracasso1            #  if(x < 10 && y < 10)
        bge a3, t2,fracasso1
        add t1, a2, a1   # x + size
       #    li t2, 10
        bge t1, t2, else3   # if not (x + size >= 10)
        blt a2, zero, else3  # if not (x < 0)
        blt a3, zero, else3  # if not (y < 0)
        bge a3, t2, else3   # if not (y >= 10)
            # letra em t3, i em t1, x em a2 e y em a3
        li t1, 0   #  i = 0
for4:
        bge t1,a2, endfor4   #   i < size
        la t5, campo
        add t5, t5, a2   #  m + x
        add t5, a5, t1   # m + x + i
        slli t4, a3, 3     # 8 * y
        slli t2, a3, 1     # 2 * y
        add t5, t5, t4   # m + x + i + 8*y
        add t5, t5, t2   # m + x + i + 10*y
        lbu t2, 0(t5)
        li t4, '~'
        bne t2, t3, else8    #  if (m[x+i][y] == '~') ...
        sb t3, 0(t5)     # m[x+i][y] = letra
        j endif8
else8:
        la a0, arrume_sobreposicao 
        li a7, 4
        ecall
            
        j endfor2    # break
endif8:
        addi t1, t1, 1
        j for4
endfor4:
        j endif3
else3:
        la a0, erro_nav 
        li a7, 4
        ecall
endif3:
endif2:
        li t1, 1
        ble a0, t1, endif5   #   if dir > 1  eh erro
        la a0, erro_direcao 
        li a7, 4
        ecall
endif5:
            #j ra   # fim
        li a7, 10   # sai sem codigo de retorno
    ecall    # fim do programa
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to observe the fundamental qualities of multi-byte data on a [byte addressable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_addressing) machine.  Words are 32 bits wide, which means they take 4 bytes of storage, each.

A pair of words starting at location X has the first word at address of X, and the second word at address of X+4, because we have to skip over all 4 of the bytes of the first word in order to reach the second word.

We also must use the proper processor instructions to access word data stored in memory.  `lw` will access location X, X+1, X+2, and X+3 to load 4 bytes of data from memory.  `lbu` will access only one byte location, so will miss 3 of the bytes of the word.

Be aware of your data types, and ensure consistency of usage.  In your program you have word data and (word) pointers as well as byte data, (byte) pointers.  Word data should always use `lw` & `sw`, while word pointers should always use multiples of 4, whereas byte data uses `lbu` and multiples of 1.  Don't treat a word data as byte data or vice versa.

---

Learn to single step the instructions of your code and verify that each instruction is doing exactly what you expect.  Most instructions have exactly one effect: loading a register with a value, or computing a sum or product, maybe storing into memory.

Also check your data before running the program, to make sure things look as you expect, and the data must be used by the program properly.

Don't wait until you have a complete program in order to verify by single stepping.  Write a small section of code, then run it to make sure it works by single stepping every instruction and verify that each does what you expect.

As you get further along in the program you can set a break point at new code instead of single stepping all the way there, then run to the break point and single step to verify the new code.